# Calling a function within a view function in Django

Tags: django, django-views

Is 1 or 2 the correct way to call a function within a view function in Django. Or are both equally ok. Please explain.

```
#1
def function1(request):
    [some api calls] 
    #Once this process is done I want to call my second function
    return function2()

def function2():
    # some hard work
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

```
#2
def function1(request):
    [some api calls] 
    #Once this process is done I want to call my second function
    function2()

def function2():
    # some hard work
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top one (#1) is the one you want.

#2 just returns the HTTP response to the original function. It returns `None` to the view itself. It doesn't work and returns this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you actually want to do with the return value of **function2()**. If you want to return this value from **function1()** , you have to use method 1, because in method 2, **function1()** just calls **function2()** , it doesn't return the value.